# Solution needed for bulk import Magento CSV

Tags: magento-1.9, import, xml, csv

For a client i need a solution to import 10.000 products (daily).

He gets a CSV or XML (both available) through FTP on a daily base.

The CSV file has custom headers.

There a no Magento default row names, “sku” for example is called “Productid” and rows needed for a product import like “status” and “website” are not there at all.

What would be the best workaround to import these products?

Comment: If this has to be done on daily basis, create a custom cron process to read the file from FTP, interpret it as per requirements, set some default parameters like status, store etc and then update products programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to grab the file from your vendor, then transform the file to meet the basic requirements for the Magento import.

Then via a night cron job you can import your file to Magento. You should report errors via an email alert or alert in the Magento admin section to warn the administrator of the issue.

Comment: The file get send to a location in the Magento root folder. How to transform the file and set default parameters that don't get provided in the CSV / XML?

Comment: You will have to create a custom module that imports, then transforms your csv or xml